# Oracle SQLPlus: print column titles in header when there is no output rows (showing "no rows selected" message)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am running an SQL command from SQLPlus command line and getting no rows.

Example:

```
select * from users;

no rows selected
```

I want to **show the column names even if there is no rows in the table**.

I tried:

```
set heading on;
```

Still no headers appeared after running the query!

I want a straight command, not tricks like concatenating fake records at the start/end of the query by union.

Comment: _Why_ do you need this? SQL*Plus doesn't do this because it doesn't make sense. There is a "describe" command that outputs the column names.

Comment: Because I don't want to run two commands to ''describe the table and its contents'' briefly.

Comment: That's what I used to do in MS SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: SQL*Plus is an ancient but wonderful tool no doubt when it comes to generating/spooling reports. But for interactive querying, I have found SQL developer to be a much better tool which would satisfy this requirement of yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done in SQL*Plus.

Two lines are necessary:

desc Users

select * from Users;

If this is for the purpose of outputting a report, in 11g you could turn off SQL*Plus headers:

set heading off;

Then add the headers yourself:

```
  SELECT listagg (column_name, ',') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) COLUMN_NAMES
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='Users';
```

and then issue the data query:  Select * from Users;

This would at least mean you always get headers.